# How to download full data in web page

Tags: c#, webclient

i am use WebClient method. Need specific data in this site. But webclient download missing data. İ am open this site in notepad++, and this lenght 314497, but webclient download 7120. I'm need help please help me.

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.ComponentModel;
            using System.Data;
            using System.Drawing;
            using System.IO;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Net;
            using System.Text;
            using System.Threading.Tasks;
            using System.Windows.Forms;

            namespace sampleapp
            {
                public partial class Form1 : Form
                {
                    public Form1()
                    {
                        InitializeComponent();
                        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                        string data=webClient.DownloadString(new Uri("blablabla"));
                        MessageBox.Show(data.Length.ToString());
                        textBox1.Text = data;



                    }
```

guys i am handle it:

```
            namespace sampleapp
            {
                public partial class Form1 : Form
                {
                    public Form1()
                    {
                        InitializeComponent();
                    }

                    private void GetWebText(string url)
                    {
                        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
                        request.UserAgent = "A .NET Web Crawler";
                        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                        string htmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        textBox1.Text = htmlText;
                        MessageBox.Show(htmlText.Length.ToString());


                    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i am noob not understand mean :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML Source of the pages you're comparing is not the same.  You can see from the first line that the doctypes are not the same.  One is strict, the other is transitional.

That is the reason the string lengths are different.

If the URL is the same, this is likely due to a difference in user agents being passes, or perhaps a session not being persisted.

Comment: İ am handle it with HttpWebRequest, thanks for answer:)